# Set background color of cells based on MySQL query output

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and trying to learn enough to do some basic functions.  I've been able to create a table for my users to edit themselves, and redisplay but I've come across a question. 
Using the script below, users can input their skill level for various products.  I wanted to be able to highlight each cell in which they input "0" or blank.  User's input will be between 0-5 (or blank if they haven't filled it in yet).

This is all being done on my localhost so I'll admit all the security measures are not quite there.

I've read a lot of posts and tried to figure it out myself, but I'm doing something fundamentally wrong I believe.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.  I've been known to buy a beer (via paypal) for those who help me with coding :)

Here is my existing code for printing out the results of the database:

```
<?php
//This will connect to the database in order to begin this page
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "time2start") or die (mysql_error());
//Now we will select the database we need to talk to
mysql_select_db("joomla_dev_15") or die (mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM enterprise_storage WHERE id=1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "$row";
echo "<tr> <th>Product</th> <th>Wayne Beeg</th> <th>Paul Hamke</th> <th>Steve Jaczyk</th>       <th>David Jontow</th> <th>Ed MacDonald</th> <th>Michael Munozcano</th> <th>Ron Shaffer</th>  <th>Luke Soares</th>  <th>Josh Wenger</th> </tr>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['model'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['beeg'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['hamke'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['jaczyk'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['jontow'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['macdonald'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['munozcano'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['shaffer'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['soares'];
echo "</td><td>"; 
echo $row['wenger'];
echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";
?>
<FORM>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Return to the Home Page"       ONCLICK="window.location.href='http://localhost/~user/joomla15/custom/skilldisplay.php'"> 
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr>";
foreach($row as $content) {
    if($content == 0) {
        echo "<td style='background-color:gray;'>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td style='background-color:green;'>";
    }
    echo $content . "</td>";
}
echo $row['wenger'];
echo "</td>"; 
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: This one didn't work either.  I pasted just as you indicated here.  The page wouldn't load after saving.  (I also changed "gray" to "red")

Comment: should that be `background-color`? `color` controls the color of the text, not the cell.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

add this to  of your generated document

```
<style type="text/css">
    .red{ background-color: red; }
</style>
```

This is your PHP:

```
<?php
// sanitize value
$value = trim($row['model']);
$class = (empty($value)) ? 'red' : '';

// display
echo "<td class=\"$class\">$value</td>"; 
...
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.  I adapted it to the $row[hamke] line which definitely has a "0" in it, but it did not change colors.  Thanks for trying though!

Comment: you are doing something wrong or misunderstanding your data. `empty(0)` and `empty('0')` will evaluate to false, unless you have some other whitespaces or special characters. See updated post above, I simplified things and added trim to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to get it working finally.  The two replies above helped me figure out the right approach to doing this.

Of course, my approach may not be the best method, but I've tested it and it works for my needs.  For any future searchers, here's what I did:

```
    <?php
    //This will connect to the database in order to begin this page
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "time2start") or die (mysql_error());
    //Now we will select the database we need to talk to
    mysql_select_db("joomla_dev_15") or die (mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT * FROM enterprise_storage";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "$row";
    echo "<tr> <th>Product</th> <th>Wayne Beeg</th> <th>Paul Hamke</th> <th>Steve Jaczyk</th> <th>David Jontow</th> <th>Ed MacDonald</th> <th>Michael Munozcano</th> <th>Ron Shaffer</th> <th><a href='http://localhost/~user/joomla15/custom/updateform.php'>Luke Soares</a></th> <th>Josh Wenger</th> </tr>";
    // keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
echo "<tr><td>"; 
echo $row['model'];
echo "</td>";
if ($row['beeg'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['beeg'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['beeg'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['hamke'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['hamke'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['hamke'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['jaczyk'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['jaczyk'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['jaczyk'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['jontow'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['jontow'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['jontow'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['macdonald'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['macdonald'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['macdonald'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['munozcano'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['munozcano'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['munozcano'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['shaffer'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['shaffer'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['shaffer'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['soares'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['soares'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['soares'];
}
echo "</td>"; 
if ($row['wenger'] == '0'){
    echo '<td bgcolor="#FF0000">' . $row['wenger'] ;
}else{
    echo '<td>' .$row['wenger'];
}
echo "</td></tr>";
```

} 
echo "";

?>